# Share the same styles between two types of component with React Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, styled-components

I would like to apply exactly the same styles to a styled `input` element and a styled `select` element.

Currently, I'm using string interpolation to do this:

```
const styles = `
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0 solid transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
`

const Select = styled.select`${styles}`
const Input = styled.input`${styles}`
```

Is there a better way of doing this which doesn't involve using a 'raw' string? The disadvantage of using the raw `styles` string is that Visual Studio Code doesn't syntax-highlight it:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have few options here:

[css helper function](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css):

```
const styles = css`
  background-color: white;
  // ...
`;

const Select = styled.select`${styles}`;
const Input = styled.input`${styles}`;
```

["as" polymorphic prop](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop) (added in **v4**):

```
<Select as="input">
  ...
</Select>
```

[withComponent method](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#withcomponent) (candidate for deprecation):

```
const Select = styled.select`
  background-color: white;
  // ...
`;
const Input = Select.withComponent('input');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`css`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css) tagged template literal:

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const styles = css`
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
`;

const Select = styled.select`${styles}`;
const Input = styled.input`${styles}`;
```

That should get properly syntax highlighted (haven't tested).